# Windows 8 Store App and Visual Studio 2012, how to stop loadasync() method?

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, visual-studio-2012, async-await

I have made a game that connects to a server to get some high scores. It works fine in the first connection (and then I close the datawriter/reader, and the streamsocket as the connection is supposed to retrieve data in one shot). 
But after I attempt a second connection I get a "InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code". A method was called at a unexpected time.

I used the template for the client connection from the following:
[StreamSocket sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/StreamSocket-Sample-8c573931)

So how can I kill all of the all the threads in the thread pool after this operation, since I think that is what is blocking the second connection?

Also this seems to be a timing issue since it will work on the second connection if I set a break point at the loadasync methods, and step through the code?

Thanks

```
    public async void ScoreUpdate(string input)
    {

        DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);
        DataReader reader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);

        string stringToSend = input;
        writer.WriteString(stringToSend);
        try
        {


            uint returnLength =  await writer.StoreAsync();
            uint sizeFieldCount = await reader.LoadAsync(4);

            if (sizeFieldCount != sizeof(uint))
            {
                // The underlying socket was closed before we were able to read the whole data.

                return;
            }

            uint stringLengthSize = reader.ReadUInt32();
            uint stringLength = await reader.LoadAsync((uint)stringLengthSize -4);
            UpdateScore = reader.ReadString(stringLength);

            socket.Dispose();
            socket = null;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // If this is an unknown status it means that the error if fatal and retry will likely fail.
            if (SocketError.GetStatus(exception.HResult) == SocketErrorStatus.Unknown)
            {
                throw;
            }
            socket.Dispose();
            socket = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show your work or your problem.?

Comment: Added the code of the sending/receiving function.

Comment: In which line do you get the exception? Where do you create the socket? When do you open the socket? Please post the exception's stack trace. InvalidOperationException doesn't mean that something is blocked. Perhaps you are simply trying to access a disposed or closed socket

Comment: BTW, the link you point to contains no templates, it's a sample project with many different scenarios. Which one did you use?

Comment: Sorry it is the steam socket example in that library of examples.

Comment: I can't tell which line breaks the program, because it will work 100% if I debug and step through the program.

Comment: I'm betting on the "`async void`". It's almost always a very bad thing. Where are you calling it form? Could it be caused by concurrency?